# 17 billions of bottles VS 17 billion of bottles

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, numbers, ielts

What is the right form for these expressions:

"In 2000 Coca-Cola has sold 17 billion**s** of bottles"

or

"In 2000 Coca-Cola has sold 17 billion of bottles"

Could you please, explain why?

---

UPDATE based on answers

The present perfect should not be used here — we know the exact year, so past simple should be used instead.

The example was inspired by the IELTS Academic [Writing Task 1](http://www.ielts-exam.net/academic_writing_samples_task_1/59/). Here is the relevant pie chart.

[image]

Comment: A related question at ELU: *[Why are the words hundred, thousand, million, and trillion singular after plural numbers?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64682/why-are-the-words-hundred-thousand-million-and-trillion-singular-after-plural)*

Comment: Another related question: *[Millions vs. Million](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16350/millions-versus-million)*

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm afraid - ***neither!***

Use *billions* when you don't have a *perfect figure* and you want to say that roughly.

> In (the year) 2000, the Coca-Cola company sold ***billions of bottles***

But you said that you have a figure. Then it's more natural if you write -

> In (the year) 2000, the Coca-Cola company sold ***17 billion bottles***

In general cases, we prefer to use the preposition when the number is not specified.

> There were ***hundreds of people*** gathered outside the White House.

But with a figure...

> There were ***three hundred*** <del>*of*</del>  people gathered outside the White House

Comment: +1, just a small detail: _in the year **of** 2000_ -> you removed one _of_, I think it is better removed here as well: _in the year 2000_.

Comment: @oerkelens hey, I think it's common to write [that way](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=*in+the+year+of*&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=HaarVMC3Ao6uuQS8n4DICQ#tbm=nws&q=%22in+the+year+of+2011%22+)!

Comment: 370 results, versus 5000 in the news category for the version without _of_. In the _web_ category_ roughly 5M versus 27M results. I'm not saying it isn't used, but it looks strange to me, and according to your own source, to a lot of people.

Comment: Okay I buy those words ;) @oerkelens

Comment: @MaulikV As a native English speaker, "in the year of 2000" sounds really strange. It's more natural to remove "of" in this phrase.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer removed. However, I *think* it works same as *The city **of** Chicago*

Comment: @MaulikV: I would _never_ say "in the year of 2011". Did you notice that most of your Google hits were from South or South-East Asia? I think this is a regional peculiarity.

Answer (score 9):

First, Coca Cola sold **17 billion bottles**, not 17 billion of bottles. You wouldn't say "one hundred of bottles."

The form "X billions of things" is an old British usage. I don't know whether it's still in use there, but you'll sometimes see it in books from the 18th and 19th centuries. It is entirely archaic, at least in the US.

So you never have to say "X billions of things" or "X millions of things." It is enough for you to understand the meaning. Saying **X billion things** is always correct and always understood.

Comment: "I don't know whether it's still in use there" -- very occasionally, but you wouldn't hear it for example on the news. It might always be consciously archaic when it is used.

Comment: I have certainly heard it being used and not, I think, always as an archaism. It foregrounds the billions. "17 billions of bottles" considers each billion to be a separate item. "hundreds of millions of pounds" is a fairly common usage in British English and works in much the same way: "how many millions?" - "hundreds of them".

Comment: Interesting. Your last example is like normal AmE usage, except that we would leave off the "s": "He makes how many million?" "Hundreds of million."